# How to store a variable amount of dates in mySQL for a reservation System?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, calendar

I am currently trying to build a reservation system for a tennis club.
The original idea was that people are paying for a subscription and play always on the same time/day in the week.
That would be fairly easy for me, but I've got told that there has to be a way to rearrange specific reservations if there's like a tournament on that day.
So i'm not familiar with MySQL(i), but I know that you can't just have an array for all the dates and add dates to it, right?

In my plan i'd have a "Customer" with Name, adress etc. and with the booked dates. How can I now have any amount of dates which I can delete, change or create with MySQL(i)?

Comment: Have one table with customers, and then add another table with userID and date. userIDs can repeat in the second table.

Comment: I'm really sorry, can you please elaborate further?

Comment: See also: The [Zero, One or Infinity Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) of [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Also `mysqli` is the driver layer, and MySQL is the database. There's nothing special about `mysqli`, and in fact, you should probably be using PDO at the absolute minimum.